# How to export reports from ASP.NET MVC application into Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-5, export

I have an application that is written using C# with ASP.NET MVC framework.

My application has lots of reports, some are data dumps and other are summary with subtotal and grand totals... The Summary repo[image]rt looks like Excel Pivot table

Currently, I am using [jQuery TableExport](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport) package to allow me to export the html report into Excel. This works, but it will export with no style.

So I wrote my own plugin that would export the HTML table with style by converting the css classes into inline-style which works.

The problem with client side export is that it is slow and takes up too much resources. If there are a large data dump, the browser may crash or the user may have to change the browser setting to allow them to export such large reports.

**Question**

What are other ways that I can use to export my with ASP.NET MVC application? I don't really want to export the report each time as in many cases the user only want to view the report. But I need to offer both functions in the case the export is needed. Is there a package the solve the reporting problems?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Where is the data coming from?  SQL views?  Stored procedures?  JSON API?  Can you not go directly from the data layer to Excel? That would be best.

Comment: Try EPPlus, I think it will do what you need.

Comment: The data is coming out of SQL database. I user Linq to get the data then I render it into an HTML table. I don’t want to go directly from database to excel becaus I don’t need excel all the time. I only need it when requested. + if I make it go directly from database and also html view, I would have to create 2 methods for each report which is something I don’t want to do since I have lots of reports